# Showing $\vec y^T S \vec x = \vec x^T S \vec y$ given some assumptions.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm given that $S^T = S$ and $S\vec{x} = \lambda \vec x$ and $S \vec y = \alpha \vec y$.

I want to show that $\vec y^T S \vec x = \vec x^T S \vec y$.

Clearly, they are both the transpose of each other and since S is symmetric then the row space is the same as the column space and not just the same, but they're spanned by the same vectors in the same order. Therefore the transpose shouldn't change anything because we're still taking the same combinations of the column and the row space.

So although I think I understand the answer, I'm looking for a more mathematical way of showing that.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ don't need to be eigenvectors for this to be true. I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're getting at with the column and row spaces, but one thing to point out is that $y^TSx$ is a scalar so automatically it will equal its own transpose.

Comment: One extra thing, if $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ are distinct, then this object $y^TSx$ is actually just zero.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&app=desktop] This series would help you develop your intuition for it. Probably, you would think of this result as obvious. All proofs need not be mathematically rigorous